# postgresql ProgrammingError: function identifier(unknown) does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to use psycopg2.sql.SQL to compose my query. I've referred to the docs but I'm unable to get this to execute. I keep getting the above programming error

Here's the example code:

```py
import psycopg2.sql as sql

query = sql.SQL("SELECT id from {} where country={}".format(sql.Identifier('country_sector'), sql.Identifier('UK')))

cur = dbobj.conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
data = cur.fetchall()
```

And here is the error:

```py
ProgrammingError: function identifier(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT id from Identifier('country_sector') where country=Id...
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This suggests to me that I need to install some extension in postgres but a lot of googling has not helped.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please try to print the content to the terminal of `Identifier('country_sector')`? What do you get?

Comment: I get the same as in the error part at LINE 1... SELECT id from Identifier('country_sector') where country=Identifier('UK')

Comment: Try to change `import psycopg2.sql as sql` to `import psycopg2 as sql`

Comment: I’m trying to use the sql module within psycopg2: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html

Comment: I can see that, but the documentation says `from psycopg2 import sql` and you are using `import psycopg2.sql as sql` That is not the same Try to rewrite that part exactly as the documentation says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `format()` wrongly. This works

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.sql as sql
conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydb' user='myuser' ")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(
sql.SQL("SELECT id from {} 
        where country=%s").format(sql.Identifier('country_sector')),
['UK']
)
data = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I believe that the issue happens when trying to pass date literal values. you can see that `mogrify()` works... but `execute` yields this error:

```
target = sql.Identifier('dwh.order_fact')
template = "SELECT count(*) FROM {target} WHERE order_date = %s"
query = sql.SQL(template.format(target=target))
cur.execute(query,['2019-01-01'])
ProgrammingError: function identifier("unknown") does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: This was the problem for me, too. I was using the `format()` method of my string, but it should be the `format()` method for the `sql.SQL` class.

Just have to move the closing parenthesis from:

query = sql.SQL("SELECT id from {} where country={}".format(sql.Identifier('country_sector'), sql.Identifier('UK')))

to:

query = sql.SQL("SELECT id from {} where country={}").format(sql.Identifier('country_sector'), sql.Identifier('UK'))

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, this solution might help.

The main takeaway is that you should use the `psycopg2.sql.format()` for the formatting of **all** named literals.

For table identifiers, note that in version 2.7.7, `sql.Identifier()` only accepts a single argument (multiple string args was added in 2.8). If you are using 2.7.7, you should format you sql template like so:

```
template = "SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} WHERE date BETWEEN {ds} and {de}"
params = {
    "schema": sql.Identifier("myschema"),
    "table": sql.Identifier("mytable"),
    "ds": sql.Literal("2019-09-01"),
    "de": sql.Literal("2019-10-01")
}
query = sql.SQL(template).format(**params)
```

If you do it correctly, `type(query)` should be `<class 'psycopg2.sql.Composed'>`

My understanding is that the `vars` param in execute is mainly intended to pass in values for INSERT, etc. Hope this helps!